# Disabling the onSelectedIndex changed event of WPF dropdown combo on navigating through arrrow keys

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When I am having a value item selected in my WPf DropDown Combo Box then navigating using keys Left and right arrow keys result in firing of selected changed event for each item.

How to overcome this problem

Comment: one way I know - is to edit a template, which contain `ContentPresenter`, and apply to it the style with 1 `EventSetter` - `PreviewKeyDown`, and inside it make some tricks, like `e.Handled = true` or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most easy and suitable way I found to overcome this problem is  as follows:

rather than using SelectedIndexChanged event I used on DropDownClosed event and all code that is wriiten earlier inside selected index changed moved to this event under a if condition that checks whether a item is selected or not. Like this.

```
 private void OnCmbOperatorsListDropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbOperatorsList.SelectedIndex != -1)
                InsertText(cmbOperatorsList.SelectedValue.ToString()); 
               //Do whatever u want with selected item
        }
```

So in this way when i navigate through Arrow keys SelectedIndexChagned event will not fired or since i haven't used that event so it will not create any problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge this is not possible straight away. I could have implemented this in a kind of "selection simulated" manner.

1. Handle arrow keys on combobox dropdown in PreviewKeyDown event by setting `e.Handled = true`. So that usual navigation based selection wont happen.
2. Inthese handlers based on Keys, change the `Background` and `Foreground` of the previous or next item from the drop down list so that it will look as if its selected and highlighted.
3. Then perform selection of the item which curently has the "simulated selection background - foreground" when dropdown closes. After dropdown closure, revert the background and foreground style.

But thats just my way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PreviewKeyDown` event like

> private void combo_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
>           {
>
> ```
>         if (e.Key.Equals(Key.Left) || (e.Key.Equals(Key.Right)))
>         {                
>            ((ComboBox)sender).SelectionChanged -= combo_SelectionChanged;
>
>         }           
>     }
> ```

and if u want to attach that event you can add this `PreviewMouseDown` event.
This is what i tried and may not be a proper method of doing such cases