# Combobox select item only by mouse or Enter key

Tags: wpf, combobox

I have a WPF `ComboBox`
I need to change default behaivor in popup list.

Now, by pressing `up` and `down` keys `SelectedItem` changes automatically.
I need change `SelectedItem` only by pressing `Enter` key, or clicking by mouse.

How can it be done?

I've subclassed `ComboBox`:

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Write("Pressed " + e.Key+ " ");
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Up || e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Down)
    {
        // ???
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}
```

This code doesn't work - no popup is shown and user can't select items.
What I shoud write and where? :)

Thanks.

**UPD1:**

I need same functionality as `ComboBox's` popup is open and user can select items by mouse.
Each item can be hovered by mouse, but not selected. Selection become only by pressing mouse button. I need the same. 'Up' and 'Down' only highlights items in popup, but `SelectedItem` will be changed only by pressing `Enter` or mouse clicking.

**UPD2:**
If I press by mouse on button, that opens Popup in ComboCox, I can highlight items in Popup by mouse, but SelectedItem will change only if I click on item.

I need same functionality by keyboard. If I start typing somewhat in ComboBox, Popup opens. And I have to hightlight items by keyboard `Up` and `Down`. TextBox in ComboBox must not change during highlighting and SelectedItem must change only if I press `Enter` (or mouse click)

**UPD3:**
Link to demo solution: [download](http://files.rsdn.ru/10267/combotest.zip)

Answer (score 3):

You should have this event handled on all the `ComboBoxItem`s in a combobox.

```
   <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
           <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown" Handler="OnPreviewKeyDown" />
        </Style> 
  </ComboBox.Resources>
```

**EDIT:**

In code behind, you can add folowing code in MyComboBox's constructor after `InitializeComponent()` do this...

```
  var comboBoxItemstyle = new Style(typeof (ComboBoxItem));  
  comboBoxItemstyle.Setters.Add(
        new EventSetter(PreviewKeyDownEvent,
                new KeyEventHandler(OnPreviewKeyDown)));
  this.Resources.Add(typeof (ComboBoxItem), comboBoxItemstyle);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have to do it from subclassed `MyComboBox` class, not in XAML. Is it possible?

Comment: I provided you XAML, your handler can be in your xaml.cs file OR if you are using MVVm then do this via attached behavior.

Comment: I have no XAML. I have only class `MyComboBox : ComboBox`, so I don't need attached behavior, because I already `inside ComboBox` :)

Comment: But you can add the `ComboboxItem` style programmatically to your MyComboBox.Resources using `this.resources.Add()` cant you?

Comment: Can you please provide a code example? I don't get how can it be done. Do you offer to write somewhere XAML code with code-behind and then add as resource inside `MyComboBox`? I don't think it's a good idea. I'm sure, there can be other solution.

Answer (score 3):

The code you have seems to work fine, just add a check to see if the DropDown is open before cancelling the Key Event

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Write("Pressed " + e.Key + " ");
    if (!base.IsDropDownOpen && (e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}
```

Comment: @Lari See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7145876/302677 The suggestion is to change the ComboBox's behavior for selecting an item so the `SelectedItem` only gets changed when the ComboBox's DropDown gets closed. If you want to keep the selection behavior when the DropDown is closed and arrow keys are pressed, then you can also handle the Key events to update the `SelectedItem`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution which worked for me -

```
public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private int _currentItemIndex;
    private string _rowColor = "#E7E7E7";
    private string _selectedRowColor = "#FFFFC6";        

    protected override void OnDropDownOpened(EventArgs e)
    {
        _currentItemIndex = base.SelectedIndex;
        base.OnDropDownOpened(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (base.IsDropDownOpen)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Up || e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                ComboBoxItem currentItem;
                var colorConverter = new BrushConverter();

                if (_currentItemIndex > -1 && _currentItemIndex != base.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    currentItem = (ComboBoxItem)base.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(_currentItemIndex);
                    currentItem.Background = (Brush)colorConverter.ConvertFromString(_rowColor);
                }

                if (e.Key == Key.Up)
                {
                    _currentItemIndex -= 1;
                    if (_currentItemIndex < 0)
                    {
                        _currentItemIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if (e.Key == Key.Down)
                {
                    _currentItemIndex += 1;
                    if (_currentItemIndex > base.Items.Count - 1)
                    {
                        _currentItemIndex = base.Items.Count - 1;
                    }
                }

                currentItem = (ComboBoxItem)base.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(_currentItemIndex);
                currentItem.Background = (Brush)colorConverter.ConvertFromString(_selectedRowColor);
                currentItem.BringIntoView();

                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                base.SelectedItem = base.Items[_currentItemIndex];
            }
        }
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnDropDownClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_currentItemIndex > -1 && base.Items[_currentItemIndex] != base.SelectedItem)
        {
            var colorConverter = new BrushConverter();
            ComboBoxItem currentItem = (ComboBoxItem)base.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(_currentItemIndex);
            currentItem.Background = (Brush)colorConverter.ConvertFromString(_rowColor);
        }
        base.OnDropDownClosed(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should create property - IsKeyNavigation (like IsMouseOver)

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.Write("Pressed " + e.Key+ " ");
    if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Up || e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Down)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "KeyNavigation", true);
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
    base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
}
```

And if Key.Up or Key.Down is pressed you should Define navigated element and change the VisualState.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the ComboBox.**OnDropDownClosed**(EventArgs) Method

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.ondropdownclosed?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ComboBox_OnDropDownClosed_System_EventArgs_

PS: For Infracistics Controls (UltraComboEditor) it´s the OnAfterCloseUp Event.

Answer (score 0):

Install a nuget package [System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/), create a class like following (NB: left/right arrows also change selection in a closed focused ComboBox):

```
public class ComboBoxCustomBehaviour: Behavior<ComboBox>
{
    private readonly ISet<Key> _dropdownBlockedKeys = new HashSet<Key>{Key.Up, Key.Down, Key.Left, Key.Right};

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += AssociatedObject_KeyDown;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= AssociatedObject_KeyDown;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_dropdownBlockedKeys.Contains(e.Key))
            e.Handled = true;
        // Use following line, when you need to stop selection only on closed ComboBox
        // e.Handled = !((ComboBox)sender).IsDropDownOpen;
    }
}
```

Add this behavior class to the xaml:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ComboBoxCustomBehaviour />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ComboBox>
```